# Entry-wise matrix norm in the limit

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms

This [Wikipedia page,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#%22Entry-wise%22_matrix_norms) defines the entry wise norm.

And says that in the limit $p \rightarrow \infty$, this is the maximum norm. How can this be shown to be true?